# In C++ is it possible to display terminal emulators such as \r, \b, or other symbols as text that have special meaning using cout?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cout

I'll provide an example:

Lets say I want to display this: "Purpose of \r"

I type in the global stream object cout: `std::cout << "Purpose of \r";`

But I end up with this displayed in the console: ""

Comment: If you have control over the special character then just make sure the \ doesn't get interpreted as a special character. Try `std::cout >> "Purpose of \\r";` and note the DOUBLE slash

Comment: Raw [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) might also help: `R"(Purpose of \r)"`